# WPF listview - Transparent background on selection and selected items

Tags: c#, wpf

i searched for some time on internet and here to find a solution on my problem, but i don't know why all the solutions i tried doesn't work. I have to say first of all that i'm totally new in WPF so maybe this can be the real problem, but i explain what i want to achieve.

I am building a WPF control i will import in another application (which is not a WPF application, but i can add WPF controls), this control is a simple listview wich have these features:
- transparent background
- border with rounded corners

I am doing this because in my other application i have a dark background with shades and i want this control to be transparent so you can see the background

Searching on internet i found what i needed, but what i am missing is to change the selected item background-foreground and the same thing when the mouse is over the item (hope it's clear)

This is the code i am using for tests:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="501" Width="792">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\\BkGd.png"></ImageBrush>
</Window.Background>

    <Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Segoe UI" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <!-- Foreground for Selected ListViewItem -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                             Color="Black"/>
                    <!-- Background for Selected ListViewItem -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

This works fine for the background and the rounded corner border, but the items keeps being highlighted with light colors and white text, whick is not good for me. What i would like to have is to have a transparent border instead of the highlighted item, both for mouse hover and selected item.

One other thing is that since i added the template, header are not shown anymore but i'd like to have header too.

Can anyone help me doing this?
Many thanks in advance

EDIT:
this is an image of what happens
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUzxB.png). I would like to have a transparent border instead

EDIT 2:
Background is an image. I tried commenting the "ListView.View" part and i have the result i want as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkF6p.png), but items are not displayed. I need to add items by code

Comment: Can you post an image of what you have and what you need?

Comment: set the background of window to transparent. That's why you are viewing background-color of window.

Comment: @Prajwal as i said in the post, the background is an image. I tried but it seems i can't add more that one properties for background. It seems that the Listview.View part causes the problem

Comment: @Prajwal I did some tests and i found this: if i remove the ListView.View part i have the result i want, even if i remove the ListView.Style part; so it seems all the work is done by the ListView.Template part. I am checking your solution but as i said i am completely new to WPF so i have some problems, i don't understand what i should do

Comment: As I said, you need to override the default style from Windows Theme. Then only you can do that. Please check out this simplistic tutorial. http://www.wpftutorial.net/styles.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\\BkGd.png"></ImageBrush> 
</Window.Background>
```

This, is actually setting up the background.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Transparent"/>
</Style.Resources>
```

is setting the selected item background to transparent. Hence, you are getting background of window. But, you are not seeing that because of that blue highlight. For that, you need to override default Control Styles.

Here's how to do that.

[Overriding Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee786835(v=surface.10).aspx)